# Delete records with a column value from an array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column called school_id in a table called records.

Now I have an array of school_ids and I want to delete all the records that has the following ids that belong to the array.

The question is, is there a way to do it with just one line of command? Like:

Record.delete_all(:school_id => [1, 2, 3, 4])?

Right now I'm doing a looping here and as much as possible I'm trying to simplify that part. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your way.  I hope you are using Rails 3.x

```
Record.delete_all(:school_id => [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

It generates SQL

```
DELETE FROM "records" WHERE "records"."school_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: actually I forgot to mention that it is in Rails 2.x

Answer (score 1):

check this out [destroy_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002274)

It expects a string, array, or hash of ids to delete.

I often add another action to the controller for destroy_multiple

```
def destroy_multiple
  current_user.entries.destroy_all(:id => params[:user_ids])
  redirect_to entries_url
end
```

don't forget to add the collection route..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about rails, but you can do it pretty easily in SQL:

`delete from records where school_id in (1,2,3,4)`

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
School.where('id IN (?)', school_ids).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Record.where(:school_id => [1, 2, 3, 4]).delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
Record.where(school_id: school_ids).delete_all
```